# How to print bold text in Heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

I have a block of Heredoc for email that I am sending out. In this block I am trying print selected text in bold/strong.

Take the following block of heredoc as an example.

```
<<<ENDINGTEXT

    Example text

    more text

    <b>This in bold</b>

ENDINGTEXT;
```

When I send above out as an email. The "b" tags do not convert the text within it to be bold. In the email it gets displayed as it is with b tags intact.

can someone please show me the way to achieve this as well some basic HTML integration in heredoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the email which you are sending does not contain `HTML` enabled headers.

You need to set the headers like this.

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

For a detailed example, see the PHP Manual [`here`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#refsect1-function.mail-examples)

Comment: The code I gave above is in my custom wordpress plugin. Doesn't wordpress include HTML header that by default?

Comment: Indeed the HTML header was not set. You can follow the answer above from Shankar Damodaran or if you are using wordpress like me then read this codex documentation to set HTML headers.